# Adding a body to a pure virtual/abstract function in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract

A pure virtual function isn't supposed to have a body, but I just noticed that the following code is accepted by the compiler:

```
class foo
{
    virtual void dummy() = 0
    {
        cout << "hello";
    }
};
```

So, why are pure virtual functions allowed to have a body? Also, even when the function has a body, the class still can't be instantiated, why is that?

Comment: [C++ corner case: You can implement pure virtual functions in the base class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/11/10455907.aspx)

Comment: I know removing =0 will allow me to create the object. But i guess this is not the question i asked. I wanted to know why we cant create object of abstract class?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal `=0` is a declaration to the compiler that you should not be able to instantiate the class until you override the method, quite independent of whether the method is actually implemented or not.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal I edited your question to make it more clear, did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but when seraching this topic you end up here... Accoring to this (draft!) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf on 11.7.3, 2 :  [Note: A function declaration cannot provide both apure-specifierand a definition.— endnote] [Example:struct C {virtual void f() = 0 { };// error};— end example]. No interpretation from my side here, you just might want to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure virtual function can have a body, but the fact that you declare them pure virtual is exactly to say that a derived implementation is **required**.

You can execute the pure virtual method from a derived method (using an explicit `BaseClass::method()`) but still you have to provide an implementation.

Not being able to instantiate a class with a pure virtual method that has not been overriden **is the main point** of the pure virtual declaration. In other words the idea of declaring a method pure virtual is to ensure that the programmer *will not forget* about providing its implementation.

Comment: Also note that you have to supply a body for a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: @AndreKostur: I don't think that (from a logical point of view) a pure virtual destructor makes much sense. Also it's not so common to have to provide a pure virtual method base class implementation (anything that can be put in the base class implementation can also be put probably more reasonably in a regular utility method). A finer semantic description of methods combination is present in Common Lisp... for C++ stretching the pure virtual to that is IMO a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, abstract class is used to define *interface* and/or *partial implementation*, and is intended to be inherited by concrete classes. It is a way of enforcing a [*contract*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) between class *designer* and *users* of that class, whatever they are.

If you don't need this contract and want instantiation, then do not enforce it to be abstract class, i.e. remove `= 0`.

If your concern is why would pure virtual functions have body in the first place, then one good example could be this quote from the **Effective C++** book by Scott Meyers:

> Derived classes that implement this pure virtual function may call
>   this implementation somewhere in their code. If part of the code of
>   two different derived classes is similar then it makes sense to move
>   it up in the hierarchy, even if the function should be pure virtual.

Another example is pure virtual destructor (which is also a function by the way):

```
...

virtual ~foo() = 0;

...

foo::~foo() {} // required!
```

when you are **required** to provide implementation for it, but at the same time want to make it pure virtual in order to make the `foo` class abstract. So, in fact, the core of the language itself relies on this feature.